Is food that tastes like chometz on Pesach "not in the spirit of the law"?
Various companies have gotten very good at making Pesach cakes and other items that taste almost identical to the chometz version. Do any poskim come out against eating foods like that from the perspective of it not being in the spirit of Pesach? In theory it would be similar to why many poskim are against acapella music during sefirah, though perhaps there's a difference being that the restrictions of sefirah are to demonstrate aveilus, which you lose out on when listening to any sort of music, as opposed to chometz which may be viewed as more of a geziras hakasuv (to put it generally. Obviously reasons are given for not eating chometz but they're beyond the scope of this question, I think)

The taste of chametz is sour. Sourdough/fermentation/leavening. Most of the foods we commonly avoid nowadays as chametz (eg. pasta, oreos) are not what the torah was telling us to avoid. You could in theory make completely kosher for pesach pasta and oreos if you make them fast enough. The reason people think pesach food tastes so different is we commonly start with matza meal instead of raw flour to avoid any mistakes where something starts fermenting. But that bad flavor/texture isn't itself of any biblical value.

The extent to which we must hold to the perceived "spirit" of the mitzvot is not a well-defined area and has generated a lot of controversy.  We have a "fence around the Torah", but not a fence around the fence.
